# How do i find out what the foreign addresses are in cmd and where they come from?

Tags: netstat, cmd.exe

Ran `netstat -a` and I was curious as to what `yx-in-f95:https` on the foreign address section is and how to find out myself in the future.

Comment: This question is out of scope on Security SE. I suggest to move it to the Superuser SE.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign address section shows the **server name or the IP address** with which connection is established.

it usually displays like below

```
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
   tcp4       0      0  1xx.1xx.2xx.1xx.532xx  server-216-137-3.https ESTABLISHED
   tcp4       0      0  1xx.1xx.2xx.1xx.531xx  stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED
   tcp4       0      0  1xx.1xx.2xx.1xx.530xx  162.247.243.146.https  ESTABLISHED
```